# How can i set product image which is in cart by observer event(checkout_cart_after_add_product) in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Below code i am doing:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');

        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $price = 100;
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

}
```

Note: in above example, custom price working properly but i also need to update product image.

Comment: http://mageclass.com/how-to-change-product-image-in-cart-and-minicart-in-magento2/
http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-change-product-image-in-minicart-in-magento-2/